# How to setup and teardown express with node?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a very basic node script that starts up, serving up an html page and finally closes the app (kills the node process ideally). Everything works great except the last line that invokes the close method to tear it down.

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, app = express()
, server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(8090);
console.log("started...");
app.close();
```

The error I get when I run this w/ node 0.8+ is

```
app.close();
    ^
TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'close'
```

Anyone know how I can more safely close the express app down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the best approach I've found it to kill the node process. seems to get the job done (although for purity I'd like to just close express)

```
process.exit(code=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were so close:

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, app = express()
, server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var listener = app.listen(8090);
console.log("started...");
listener.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  app.close();
});
```

Try that

Comment: so if I understand this -it allows me to run the above and when I hit control -c from the terminal it will kill the app w/out an exception? If that is the case how can I automate this ctl-c action from within node? I need to have this be self contained if possible

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. I don't understand the use case then. Under what conditions should this application terminate itself? Are you wanting this node app to start on demand, serve a page, then stop? I'm lost now :)

Comment: I'm creating a js test runner with phantom js and because phantom requires a server be up I'm using the code above to help make this process truly cmd line friendly (no need to run anything through a browser). Here is a gist that shows what I have so far to run jasmine tests with phantom and node https://gist.github.com/3664785

Comment: See Toran's answer in that case, I don't think there's any need to explicitly clean up express.